# Session Error While Using WebdriverIO with Appium on Android Device

Tags: javascript, cucumber, appium, webdriver-io

I cloned the repo https://github.com/Schveitzer/webdriverio-appium-cucumber-boilerplate and tried to run the tests.
I consistently get the following error.

```
2022-06-16T22:51:13.157Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
Unable to connect to "http://localhost:4723/", make sure browser driver is running on that address.
If you use services like chromedriver see initialiseServices logs above or in wdio.log file as the service might had problems to start the driver.
```

Steps:

1. Clone the repo
2. Download the latest version of the demo app which Android-NativeDemoApp-0.4.0.apk. The one in the repo does not work.
3. Update the capabilities.
4. Yarn Install/Yarn Run

I made some changes. However, was not able to resolve the issue. Any suggestions to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it seems that appium server is not running. One reason could be that the repo has an old version of packages and you might have installed the latest version of appium.

One thing you could try is to remove the [this](https://github.com/Schveitzer/webdriverio-appium-cucumber-boilerplate/blob/master/config/wdio.shared.conf.js#L51) line from the config file and try the below.

1. Start the appium server using the command `appium` on terminal
2. Run your tests and see if it works

Otherwise, you have to upgrade all the packages in the repo. but this also means you may have to change something in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your appium server is likely not running, from package.json I can see that the appium-service that is supposed to get it up is missing. You have two options:

1. install the @wdio/appium-service package, and appium should run automatically or
2. start the appium server yourself, either from the terminal with `appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723` or launch the appium desktop app

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that WebDriverIO is unable to connect to the Appium server running on http://127.0.0.1:4723/.

Few steps to resolve this issue:

1. Check that the Appium server is running on http://127.0.0.1:4723/.
   You can check this by opening a web browser and navigating to
   http://127.0.0.1:4723/. If the server is running, you should see a
   message indicating that the server is running and ready to accept
   connections.
2. Check that the chromedriver executable is installed and in your
   system's PATH. WebDriverIO uses chromedriver to interact with the
   Chrome browser on Android devices. You can install chromedriver
   using npm by running the following command:

```
npm install -g chromedriver
```

3. Check that the `@wdio/appium-service` is included in the services
   array in your wdio.conf.js file:

```
services: ['appium']
```